# Multiprocessing-spawn process fails to terminate after call to return

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I think there's a fairly high likelihood that this question has been asked before, but I was unable to find an appropriate solution.

I'm using python multiprocessing. Sometimes, all of my child processes terminate and return appropriately. Other times, they don't. This is the way with parallel processes, I suppose. What's odd is that the very last thing the child processes are supposed to do is:

```
job = q.get()
if job == None:
    q.put(None)
    print 'Got nothing, exiting'
    return
```

This message is always printed. It appears that it is stuck waiting for something, but I'm not sure what that could be. Everything it's using is declared to be threadsafe by online documentation. I'm not really certain what it *could* be waiting for, which is making searching for a solution difficult. One potential problem is that the child processes enqueue mutable lists in a 'return' queue, but I haven't found anything that would indicate that that is problematic. Thanks!

Edit: Removing the portion of the child process that enqueues the results in the results queue appears to abolish the issue. However, I believe that the results queue should be threadsafe, and hence this shouldn't be an issue.